# Broken Binary search and Bubble sort

Tags: c, binary-search, bubble-sort, arrayofstring

I really need some help with this problem, this program we are supposed to debug has some errors in it that I cannot find.

The program has an array of names and is supposed to bubble sort the names to alphabetical order and then let the user search for a name.

The bubble sort doesn't seem to do anything, and the search always says the name cannot be found.

Some help would be great on how to fix this. Thank-you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_OF_NAMES 8
#define NAME_SIZE 5

void printNames(char names[][5], int size);
void bubbleSortNames(char names[][5], int last);
bool binarySearchNames(char list[][5], int end, char target[], int *location);

int main()
{
        char nameList[8][5]={"Zack","Jake","Jill","Seth","Eric","Beth","Hugh","Rita"},
                  searchText[5],
                  userChoice;
        int  searchLocation,
                  last = 0;

        printNames(nameList, 8);

        printf("\n\nLIST AFTER SORT\n\n");

        bubbleSortNames(nameList, last);
        printNames(nameList, 8);

        printf("Would youy like to search for a name? (y/n) ");
        scanf(" %c", &userChoice);

        while(userChoice == 'y')
        {
                printf("\nPlease try and search for a name: ");
                scanf("%20s", searchText);

                if(binarySearchNames(nameList, 8, searchText, &searchLocation))
                        printf("\nThe name %s was not found. :(\n", searchText);

                else
                        printf("\nThe name %s was found at location %d!", searchText, searchLocation);

                printf("\nWould you like to search for another name? (y/n) ");
                scanf(" %c", &userChoice);
        }
        printf("\nThank you for using this program.\n\n");

        return 0;
}

/*
 Prints out array of names
*/
void printNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int size)
{
        for(int index = 0; index <= size; index++)
        puts(names[index]);
        return;
}
/*
 Sorts names alphabetically
*/
void bubbleSortNames(char names[][NAME_SIZE], int last)
{
        char temp[NAME_SIZE];

        for(int current = 0; current < last; current++)
                {
                        for(int walker = last; walker > current; walker--)
                                if(strcmp(names[walker], names[walker - 1]))
                                {
                                        strcpy(temp, names[walker]);
                                        strcpy(names[walker], names[walker - 1]);
                                        strcpy(names[walker - 1], temp);
                                }
                }
        return;
        }
/*
 Searches for name entered
*/
bool binarySearchNames(char list[][NAME_SIZE], int end, char target[], int *location)
{
        char first = 0,
             last = end,
             mid;

        while(first <= last)
        {
                mid = (first + last) / 2;

                if(target > list[mid])
                         first = mid + 1;
                else if(target < list[mid])
                        last = mid - 1;
                else
                        first = last +  1;
        }

        *location = mid;
        return target = list[mid];
}
```

Comment: You can't just post a bunch of code and say it doesn't work and expect SO to fix it.

Comment: `if(strcmp(names[walker], names[walker - 1]))` <- you should read the man page for `strcmp` (or any spec if you don't have man pages).

Comment: What did you discover while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

1) wrong number

`last = 0;`  ---->  `last = NUM_OF_NAMES -1;`

2)Execution statement is opposite to the conditions. and 8 ----> last

```
if(binarySearchNames(nameList, 8, searchText, &searchLocation))
    printf("\nThe name %s was not found. :(\n", searchText);
else
    printf("\nThe name %s was found at location %d!", searchText, searchLocation);
```

3) at printNames

`index <= size`  ----> `index < size` or call by 8 ----> call by last

4) at bubbleSortNames

`if(strcmp(names[walker], names[walker - 1]))`

to

`if(strcmp(names[walker], names[walker - 1])<0)`

5) at binarySearchNames

use `strcmp` to compare strings